# How and when did “give it up for someone” start to mean asking for applause?

Tags: etymology, phrases, expressions

I recently attended a meeting where the speaker frequently used the phrase *give it up for someone*. I understand that this expression means to clap for the person or group mentioned. It is similar to *give someone a hand*.

Where did this phrase originate? I don’t exactly get why giving it up means clapping.

Comment: OED says *colloq. (orig. U.S.).* Their earliest citation is *1990   Re: ShrinkIt 3.0 in comp.sys.apple2 (Usenet newsgroup) 30 Mar.,   Hey folks, let's give it up for Andy! One huge round of applause please!*. I imagine it alludes to ***raising*** your hands (from your lap, or hanging by your side) in order to clap.

Comment: @tchrist: Actually, I thought it was a *Briticism*, and I'm surprised to see it's so recent. We have a lot more televised "comedy club stand-ups" these days (cheap programming, I guess), and the comperes *always* seem to use this intro/outro. We (or more properly, the *comperes*) obviously really like it, to have adopted it so quickly and comprehensively.

Comment: @user814064: Nice catch! I suppose you don't have enough rep to *closevote* as a dup, but you might have been able to *flag* it to get a mod on the case. Whatever - it'll take 4 more closevotes from lesser mortals like me, but I'm certainly convinced.

Comment: I looked at the existing questions and did not see the other question.

Comment: @ Timtech: No shame in that. Apparently neither Wendikidd, StoneyB, nor myself were able to find the duplicate either. If you searched for *"give it up for"* most likely the SO search engine would simply ignore all but the first word. And if we have multiple questions on the same issue that probably means more people are *interested* in it. Future visitors have more chance of finding the answer even if all the dups are closed, because the questions will all be phrased slightly differently (but they should all lead to the same "retained" question, which hopefully has the "best" answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is a very recent thing, and is still considered “wrong” by plenty of folks.

But it is documented.

The OED’s first citation of this oddity is from a 1990 USENET posting:

> “Hey folks, let’s give it up for Andy! One huge round of applause please!”

It means to show appreciation for an entertainer, usually by another, and is usually in the imperative (“Let’s give it up for”).

Further citations date from the 1990s on either side of the pond.

This use may be related to the far older *to give it out*, which dates from the 14<sup>th</sup> century.

See [here](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/04/give-it-up.html) for more.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't really a "phrase" in the sense you're suggesting. "Give it up" is requesting (in a literal sense) to give your clap. The clap is yours. I think you should watch http://youtu.be/ZD037VSAG2I. The video does a great job of explaining: The clap; history, origin, future, etc. of the clap. It's called "Why we clap" by Vsauce.